# Convert 2 bytes into 12 bit number?

Tags: c, byte, bit-shift

I'm working in C, and assume I have 2 bytes in little endian:

```
buffer[0] = 0x01; buffer[1] = 0x02;
```

How can I convert the above into a combined 12 bit number? So after combining it should look like:

```
0x0201
```

Comment: `0x0201` looks like a 16-bit number.  Did you mean `0x201`?

Comment: You have 2 bytes, which is 16 bits. 12 bits is 1 and a half bytes. 3 bytes would be 24 bits (all assuming 8 bit bytes). I think you need to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Is `buffer[]` of type `char`, `unsigned char`, `uint8_t` or something else?

Comment: If you have two bytes and both are truly ranged 0 to 255 like fully ranged bytes are, you can't fit them both in 12 bits. So you need to indicate what your assumptions are. Do either or both bytes have a limited range? 0 to what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a 16 bit number. each byte is 8 bits.

`int i = (buffer[0] & 0xFF) | (buffer[1] << 8);`

If you want 12 bits then this

`int i = (buffer[0] & 0xFF) | ((buffer[1] & 0x0F) << 8);`

Convert back to buffer

```
char buffer[2];
buffer[0] = i & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = (i >> 8) & 0x0F;
```

Comment: The buffer is in little endian, so will this also convert it back to regular form as well?

Comment: Yes. Added how to put it back to the buffer from an int.

Answer (score 2):

3 bytes (24 bits) number:

```
number = ((buffer[2] & 0x0F) << 16) | ((buffer[1] & 0x0F) << 8) | buffer[0];
```

2 bytes (16 bits) number:

```
number = ((buffer[2] & 0x0F) << 8) | ((buffer[1] & 0x0F) << 4) | buffer[0];
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I only need to convert 2 bytes into a combined 12 bit number?

Comment: 2 bytes make up a 16 bit number. I don't understand why you are thinking of a 12 bit number.

Comment: Addition is not the same as OR

Comment: I'm reading in bytes, but I need the 12 bit number. I essentially need to ignore a portion of the 2nd byte.

Answer (score 1):

In case `buffer[]` is a signed type use

```
int twelve_bit1 = ((buffer[1] & 0xF) << 8) | (buffer[0] & 0xFF);
```

or

```
int twelve_bit2 = ((buffer[1] & 0xF) << 8) | (unsigned char) buffer[0];
```

or

```
int twelve_bit3 = ((buffer[1] & 15) * 256) | buffer[0] & 255;
```

All generate similar code.